# Log true if an array containing multiple objects has a set of key-value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to log `true` if an array containing multiple objects has a set of key-value pairs as per my requirements.

My code:

```
var myArray = [
  {'key' : "test 0", 'value' : 0},
  {'key' : "test 1", 'value' : 1},
  {'key' : "SELECT_ME", 'value' : 2}, // Index : 2
  {'key' : "test 3", 'value' : 3},
  {'key' : "SELECT_YOU", 'value' : 4} // Index: 4
];
```

I want here : If all the objects inside "myArray" has some key-value pair then "myArray" should return "true".

EXAMPLE: Index:2 and Index:4 objects has key-value pair of `'key' : "SELECT_ME"` and `'key' : "SELECT_YOU"` respectively. Then "myArray" should return "true" in this case.

Comment: How can myArray return true ? It is an array. Can you post the code you have written ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myArray.every(pair=>"key" in pair && "value" in pair)) alert("valid");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the given property is equal to a given value/values by using a key and [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for iterating.

```js
function check(array, key, values) {
    values = [].concat(values);
    return array.some(function (o) {
        return values.indexOf(o[key]) !== -1;
    });
}

var array = [{ key: "test 0", value: 0 }, { key: "test 1", value: 1 }, { key: "SELECT_ME", value: 2 }, { key: "test 3", value: 3 }, { key: "SELECT_YOU", value: 4 }];

console.log(check(array, 'key', ['SELECT_ME', 'SELECT_YOU'])); // true
console.log(check(array, 'key', 'SELECT_ME'));                 // true
console.log(check(array, 'value', 3));                         // true
console.log(check(array, 'key', 'foo'));                       // false
```